Endpoint exists and shows up in My Account dashboard. Need to add endpoint to My Account DROPDOWN menu in Porto theme
NOTE: StackOverflow closed this question claiming it was a duplicate but there isn't any similar questions. I looked through the other "similar" questions but those were in regards to adding endpoints to the My Account menu. My issue is that the endpoint exists and shows up in the My Account menu but it is missing from the My Account DROPDOWN menu that is part of the Porto theme.
I'm building a Wordpress site and use the Porto Theme that came bundled with the YITH Wishlist plugin integrated into the design. The only thing that doesn't make sense is that the My Account Dashboard has the Wishlist link but the dropdown menu doesn't contain the Wishlist link. I have two other 3rd party plugins that automatically added the links (Store Credit and Trout Points & Rewards) to both the My Account Dashboard and dropdown menu. How does a 3rd party plugin make this happen yet the bundled plugin doesn't? I spoke to Porto support who are normally excellent but they said that it was the default behavior. To me it seems more like a design oversight though. They said I would need a custom solution to add that to the dropdown menu. Can anyone tell me how to add the Wishlist to the dropdown menu where the red arrow is on the screenshot?


I haven't tried any coding on my own because this is above my skill level.
This is what inspecting the html of my dropdown looks like (Wishlist is missing):
<ul class="porto-narrow-sub-menu sub-menu pos-left">
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--dashboard is-active menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--orders menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/orders/">Orders</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--store-credit menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/store-credit/">Store Credits</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--downloads menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/downloads/">Downloads</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--edit-address menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/edit-address/">Addresses</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--payment-methods menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/payment-methods/">Payment methods</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--edit-account menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/edit-account/">Account details</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--loyalty_reward menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/loyalty_reward/">Trout Points &amp; Rewards</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--customer-logout menu-item">
        <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=108b381e92">Log out</a>
    </li>
</ul>

Here is the html of the dashboard (Wishlist is there):
<nav class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation">
    <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-md text-uppercase pt-1 m-b-sm">My account</h5>
    <ul>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--dashboard is-active">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--orders">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/orders/">Orders</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--store-credit">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/store-credit/">Store Credits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--downloads">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/downloads/">Downloads</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--edit-address">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/edit-address/">Addresses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--payment-methods">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/payment-methods/">Payment methods</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--edit-account">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/edit-account/">Account details</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--loyalty_reward">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/loyalty_reward/">Trout Points &amp; Rewards</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--wishlist">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/wishlist/">Wishlist</a>
            </li>
            <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--customer-logout">
                <a href="https://troutartsupply.com/trouttemp2024/my-account-2/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=108b381e92">Log out</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


Commercial third party themes are off topic here, and even if they weren't nobody would be able to help you without access to the theme and the plugin. This is the sort of situation where you're going to need to hire someone.

Ok thanks for the reply.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
